# alternative for python pivot_table for frequency table of two variables

Tags: python, r, pivot-table, frequency

For a data like this

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'group1': list('AABBCCAABBCC'),'group2':list('ZYYXYXXYZXYZ')})
```

I figured out with some difficulty that to make a frequency table of rows and columns, the most common way is as follows

```
print df.pivot_table(index='group1',columns='group2',aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)
```

by which I get

```
group2  X  Y  Z
group1         
A       1  2  1
B       2  1  1
C       1  2  1
```

I am just wondering if there are any 'faster' way to generate the same table.  Not that there is anything wrong with it but what I mean is something which involve less typing (without me having to write a custom function)

I am just comparing this with R where same result could have been achieved by

```
 table(df$group1,df$group2)
```

Compared to this, entering non default parameters like `aggfunc` and `fill_value` and typing out argument names, `index` and `columns` seems lot of additional effort.

In general my experience (very limited) is that R equivalent functions in python are very similar in conciseness.

Any suggestions on alternative methods would be great. I will need to make several of these tables with my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.crosstab(df['group1'],df['group2'])
```

This was exactly what I was looking for. Did not find it when I was searching for it initially.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method.

```
>>> df.groupby(['group1', 'group2']).group2.count().unstack().fillna(0)
group2  X  Y  Z
group1         
A       1  2  1
B       2  1  1
C       1  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. Still very verbose compared to elegant solution in R using `table`.  Sounds like cannot avoid this extra typing in python.

Comment: @ Alexander, actually your solution works much better if the data frame has several columns . The code I posted does something I do not understand why for multiple columns but your solution still gives me exactly why I want..!